# Can a pro-verb be followed by a noun phrase?

Tags: verbs

I’m confusing whether a pro-verb can be followed by a noun phrase. For example, in “*I like Japanese, but my brother* ***likes*** *Chinese*,” can I use ***does*** instead of *likes*?

Comment: I think you can. If **does not** fits well here, why not **does**! *I like Japanese, but my brother does not (like Japanese).*

Comment: @MaulikV In your example, the presence of an auxiliary (*do*) allows you to omit the following verb phrase (*like Japanese*) because it's recoverable from context.  That is unlike Listenever's example, where *do* is a lexical verb and nothing is omitted.

Comment: A really good question! I'm going to say, off the top of my head, No - that "do" stands for a VP just as pronouns stand for NPs. But I am not confident.

Comment: Not an answer to the question but examples on how to use the auxiliary 'do': I like Japanese, but my brother doesn't (like Japanese).  Alternatively, "I don't like Chinese, but my brother does (like it)." But if you both like Japanese you can say: "I like Japanese as/so does my brother."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both clauses had the same object (either Japanese, or Chinese), you could use "does". For example, if you and your brother both like Japanese, all of these sentences with "does" as a pro-verb are correct:

> I like Japanese, and so does my brother.
>   I like Japanese, as does my brother.
>   I like Japanese and my brother does, too.

However, there is a problem with saying "I like Japanese, but my brother does Chinese". One meaning of "does" is "working at/on". Using "does" implies that your brother works on Chinese in some way--perhaps he studies Chinese, or takes a Chinese course. It is common to say things like:

> My brother does Chinese at university.
>   My brother does Chinese homework.

Because of the meaning of "does", saying "my brother does Chinese" makes our sentence confusing. So we cannot use "does" in this case. The correct way to write the sentence is:

> I like Japanese, but my brother likes Chinese.

Comment: Maybe it's an AmE thing, but "My brother does Chinese at university." sounds incredibly awkward to me.